# INNER JOIN Syntax Error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to JOIN 2 databases.

- 1 database is keyword_data (keyword mapping)
- 1 database is filled with Google rankings and other metrics

Somehow I cannot JOIN these two databases.

Some context:

**DATA SET NAME: visibility**

**TABLE 1**

keyword_data

**VALUES**

- keyword
- universe
- category
- search_volume
- cpc

**DATA SET NAME: visibility**

**TABLE 2**

results

**VALUES**

- Date
- Keyword
- Website
- Position

In order to receive ranking data by date I wrote the following SQL line.

```
SELECT Date, Position, Website FROM `visibility.results` Keyword INNER
JOIN `visibility.keyword_data` keyword ON `visibility.results` Keyword
= `visibility.keyword_data` keyword GROUP BY Date;
```

(besides that, 100 other lines with no success ;-) )

I am using Google BigQuery for this with standard SQL (unchecked Legacy SQL).

How can I JOIN those 2 data tables?

Comment: what is your expected result? - provide example

Answer (score 2):

How familiar are you with SQL? I think you're using aliases wrong, something like this should work

```
SELECT r.Date, r.Position, r.Website
FROM `visibility.results` AS r
INNER JOIN `visibility.keyword_data` AS k
ON r.Keyword = k.keyword
GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: I am learning :-)

Get the following Error:

Error: SELECT list expression references r.Position which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Is it possible it has something to do with position of 'AS'?

Comment: Seems a Google BigQuery thing, which I am not familiar with, sorry

Comment: It's not specific to BigQuery. When you use GROUP BY, every column in the SELECT list either needs to appear in the GROUP BY list or be the result of an aggregate function (such as SUM, COUNT, etc.). `GROUP BY Date, Position, Website` would work, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have never worked with Google big query but there is a couple of things wrong in my opinion with this query.

To start with you join tables by including the name of the table then you provide the key that the tables are joined by. Also if you don't use aggregate functions (MIN/MAX etc.) in your select statement you must include all values in the group by clause as well. In reference I can provide you a solution that would work if you would of used Microsoft SQL Server if that would be of any help because if you reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) the syntax is quite similar.

```
SELECT  results.Date AS DATE, 
       ,results.Position AS POSITION
       ,results.Website AS WEBSITE
FROM visibility.dbo.keyword_data AS keyword_data  
INNER JOIN visibility.dbo.results AS results 
ON results.keyword = keyword_data.keyword
GROUP BY results.Date
        ,results.Position
        ,results.Website
```